# Linear Gradient with Next.js Image Component

Tags: css, reactjs, next.js, nextjs-image, styled-jsx

I want to set a background image with the Image component and set a linear-gradient over it. So far, no luck. I've tried simply placing a `linear-gradient` as the background of the image component. Putting the Image component in a `div` and putting a `linear-gradient` on that. And finally the code below.

```js
<div className="hero-image-container">
            <div className="bg-image-filter" />
            <div className="bg-image">
              <Image
                alt="Background"
                className="hero-image"
                layout="fill"
                objectFit="cover"
                src={image}
              />
            </div>
          </div>
<style jsx>{`
        .bg-image {
          z-index: -10;
        }
        .bg-image-filter {
          z-index: 10;
          background: linear-gradient(
            to right bottom,
            rgba(90, 76, 16, 0.6),
            rgba(20, 81, 116, 0.3)
          );
          object-fit: cover;
        }
        .hero {
          min-height: 85vh;
        }
        .hero-image-container {
          height: 85vh;
          width: 100vw;
          position: absolute;
          z-index: 0;
        }
        .hero-image {
          position: relative; !important
        }
      `}</style>
```

I can get the `linear-gradient` to work sans image, of course. The issue might be this breaks the optimization paradigm with the component. Or I might just not know what I'm doing. Any thoughts?

Note: I'm aware of a similar question someone posted, but it has been abandoned unanswered.

Comment: Try adding `width: 100%; height: 100%; position: absolute` to the `.bg-image-filter` selector.